# How do I align the following table cell in the middle?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have the following table, and I want the `1` to appear centered in the left column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|p{1in}|}
\hline
1 & a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: change `l` to `c` in the tabular argument (or do you mean vertical center, in which case change  to `m` and add `\usepackage{array}`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think he/she is talking vertical centering...

Comment: Cumbersome, but, `1 & \parbox[c]{1in}{a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle only if you also include the `array` or `tabularx` package...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You edited your comment without me noticing... two can play at that game.

Answer (score 1):

I have added to David's solution (in a comment to your question) the width `\myw` to have a column of the exact width of the string `1`, if you also have numbers of 2 or 3 digits just change `\settowidth{\myw}{...}` or put any width you like within the column definition `m{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newlength{\myw}
\settowidth{\myw}{1}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\emph{David's solution (with \textbackslash\texttt{array} package)}

    Note that both colums must have \texttt{m\{\dots\}} type.
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|m{\myw}|m{1in}|}
        \hline
        1 & a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \noindent\emph{Steven's solution (with no extra packages)}

    Note that it's necessary to explicity give the height of the \arraybackslash\texttt{parbox}. 
    Otherwise, the lines overlap the text.
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|p{1in}|}
        \hline
        1 & \parbox[c][1.2\height]{1in}{a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]